# Outgrowing Time Capsule: drobo, synology, os x server on mac mini?

Tags: macos, time-machine, time-capsule, server.app

We have 14 macs in an office backing up to a 2TB Time Capsule, which sometimes shows delays but generally works.  We need more space and while I can upgrade the drive to a 4TB I have a feeling we are working the hardware pretty hard so I'm looking at other options.

We are using the user account based backups on the time capsule; users backups should ideally be encrypted but at the very least need to have file permissions so that users can not see other users' backups.  I would also like to have a quota for time machine backup size per user, which I understand isn't really supported in OS X Server but can be done with hand-created sparsebundles (ugh).  With the drobo you have to create a volume per user but can enforce the size that way.

Does anyone have experience running Time Capsule successfully in an environment with around 10 to 50 computers?  I am looking at a Drobo (probably 5N), Mac Mini Server with a disk array, or perhaps a Synology unit.  4TB is enough for now but I would like the storage to be expandable.

Finally, should I be using a cloud based service like CrashPlan?  I really like the ability to restore a mac that has been lost or destroyed, and the fact that Time Capsule doesn't cause WAN traffic, but I don't like sys admin time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is rather broad and can't easily be answered by a single answer. Can you try to break it down into individual parts and ask separate questions for those?